# Do not UPDATE column if it is not NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query in my prepared statement:

```
UPDATE users SET name = ?, city = ?, country = ?, status = ? WHERE id = ?
```

Some city and country values in the table are null and some others are not. I want the above query to update name and status; but if city and country are not null, do not update city and country. Is that possible with one query?

One option I have is to have another query before this one and check if the city and country values are null for this user, but I would like to keep it in one query if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()`:

```
UPDATE users
    SET name = ?,
        city = COALESCE(city, ?),
        country = COALESCE(country, ?),
        status = ?
    WHERE id = ?;
```

This will keep non-`NULL` values in `city` and `country`.  The other columns will be updated.